# How to represent 3As as "AAA" or 3Bs as BBB in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java code to represent the grades that students achieved in an exam. When you input the number 10 in the bar labelled # of grade As, and input the number 20 in the bar labelled # of grade Bs, and do it until you reach # of grade E, and then you click on the label "Display bar chart", you get a chart with the output Grade As : 10 ....Grade Bs : 20............Grade E : something. My question to you is this. If, instead of having the output Grade A : 10, I want the output AAAAAAAAAA (ie the letter A written out 10 times), how do I do it? I've thought about it all day but still can't come up with an answer.

Second (related) question: if NO students achieve any particular grade (let's say nobody scored an A), then there should be no grade letters displayed in that bar (the bar for grade A). Could someone please tell me how I should modify my code to take this into account? Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class GradeChart extends JFrame
         implements ActionListener {


    private JTextField gradeAField = new JTextField( 5 );
    private JTextField gradeBField = new JTextField( 5 );
    private JTextField gradeCField = new JTextField( 5 );
    private JTextField gradeDField = new JTextField( 5 );
    private JTextField gradeEField = new JTextField( 5 );


    private int gradeAs;
    private int gradeBs;
    private int gradeCs; 
    private int gradeDs;
    private int gradeEs;


    private JButton displayChartButton = new JButton( "Display bar chart" );
    private JButton displayDataFieldsButton = new JButton( "Clear data fields" );


    private JPanel chartPanel = new JPanel();


    private Color chartPanelColor = Color.cyan;


    private final Font labelFont = new Font( "Serif", Font.BOLD, 16 );

    // Various fixed coordinates and dimensions


    private final int chartLeftXA = 30;
    private final int chartLeftXB = 30;
    private final int chartLeftXC = 30;
    private final int chartLeftXD = 30;
    private final int chartLeftXE = 30;


    private final int chartTopYA = 50;
    private final int chartTopYB = 102;
    private final int chartTopYC = 154;
    private final int chartTopYD = 206;
    private final int chartTopYE = 258;


    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        GradeChart chart = new GradeChart();
        chart.setSize( 550, 550 );
        chart.createGUI();
        chart.setVisible( true );

    }  

    private void createGUI() {

        // Set up main window characteristics
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );


        JLabel gradeAFieldLabel = new JLabel( "# of grade As:" );
        gradeAFieldLabel.setFont( labelFont );
        window.add( gradeAFieldLabel );
        window.add( gradeAField );

        JLabel gradeBFieldLabel = new JLabel( "# of grade Bs:" );
        gradeBFieldLabel.setFont( labelFont );
        window.add( gradeBFieldLabel );
        window.add( gradeBField );

        JLabel gradeCFieldLabel = new JLabel( "# of grade Cs:" );
        gradeCFieldLabel.setFont( labelFont );
        window.add( gradeCFieldLabel );
        window.add( gradeCField );

        JLabel gradeDFieldLabel = new JLabel( "# of grade Ds:" );
        gradeDFieldLabel.setFont( labelFont );
        window.add( gradeDFieldLabel );
        window.add( gradeDField );

        JLabel gradeEFieldLabel = new JLabel( "# of grade Es:" );
        gradeEFieldLabel.setFont( labelFont );
        window.add( gradeEFieldLabel );
        window.add( gradeEField );


        window.add( displayChartButton );
        displayChartButton.addActionListener( this );

        window.add( displayDataFieldsButton );
        displayDataFieldsButton.addActionListener( this );


        chartPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 450, 300 ) );
        chartPanel.setBackground( chartPanelColor );
        window.add( chartPanel );


    }


    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {

        if ( e.getSource() == displayChartButton ) {

            checkAndRecordData();

            Graphics g = chartPanel.getGraphics();



            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(20,20,410,52);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(20,20,410,52);
            g.setColor( Color.black );
            g.drawString( "Grade As: " + gradeAs, chartLeftXA, chartTopYA );

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(20,72,410,52);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(20,72,410,52);
            g.setColor( Color.black );
            g.drawString( "Grade Bs: " + gradeBs, chartLeftXB, chartTopYB );

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(20,124,410,52);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(20,124,410,52);
            g.setColor( Color.black );
            g.setColor( Color.black );
            g.drawString( "Grade Cs: " + gradeCs, chartLeftXC, chartTopYC );

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(20,176,410,52);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(20,176,410,52);
            g.setColor( Color.black );
            g.setColor( Color.black );
            g.drawString( "Grade Ds: " + gradeDs, chartLeftXD, chartTopYD );

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(20,228,410,52);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(20,228,410,52);
            g.setColor( Color.black );
            g.setColor( Color.black );
            g.drawString( "Grade Es: " + gradeEs, chartLeftXE, chartTopYE );

        }

        if ( e.getSource() == displayDataFieldsButton ) {

            gradeAField.setText("");
            gradeBField.setText("");
            gradeCField.setText("");
            gradeDField.setText("");
            gradeEField.setText("");

        }
    }  // End of actionPerformed


    private void checkAndRecordData() {

        int tempAs = 0; 
        int tempBs = 0;
        int tempCs = 0;
        int tempDs = 0;
        int tempEs = 0;


        tempAs = Integer.parseInt( gradeAField.getText() );
        tempBs = Integer.parseInt( gradeBField.getText() );
        tempCs = Integer.parseInt( gradeCField.getText() );
        tempDs = Integer.parseInt( gradeDField.getText() );
        tempEs = Integer.parseInt( gradeEField.getText() );


        gradeAs = tempAs;
        gradeBs = tempBs;
        gradeCs = tempCs;
        gradeDs = tempDs;
        gradeEs = tempEs;

    }
```

Comment: "I've thought about it all day but still can't come up with an answer." - It's almost like you were caught in some kind of ***loop***.

Comment: Loop would be good. Also look into using String.format() as a possible solution, maybe along with a loop.

Comment: WXKevin, hello, and thanks for the String.format() hint. Will look it up in on the net.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop:

```
String longString = "";
for (int i=0; i<numOfLetter; i++) {
    longString += gradeLetter;
}
```

Or, if you have Apache Commons available:

```
String longString = StringUtils.repeat(gradeLetter, numOfLetter);
```

Comment: Loop is fine but if speed mattered, using `StringBuilder` is a lot more efficient.

Comment: @Sean unless we're talking about significantly large strings it usually isn't a big enough issue to worry about it.

Comment: Don't modern versions of the Java compiler just optimize String to StringBuilder in the bytecode, anyway?

Comment: Agree. No the compiler could not optimize this, but it's allowed to optimize expressions like "a" + foo + "b".

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a few:

```
String someAs = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA".substring(0, length);
```

Comment: Clever way of doing it ;9

Comment: There's also a way to use this trick for zero-extending a number, but it's bit too involved for a comment and I don't want to do another "answer".

Comment: Hot Licks, much appreciated.